# Can I look up a web app context url from a eager ApplicationScoped managed bean?

Tags: jsf

I want to get a web application context url (ex.: `http://myserver:8080/myApp`) and store it in the database at startup.

I know how to hook a method call in the startup by using: `@ApplicationScoped` combined with `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` and `@PostConstruct`

And  `ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath()` will give me the context path.

However, since the method annotated with `@PostConstruct` is not being triggered by a request (since it's eager) getRequestContextPath() is giving me `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your question, eager `@ApplicationScoped` bean cannot access to the context in `@PostConstruct` since there's no request-response cycle. Instead, use [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to listen when the application is deployed/undeployed.

```
public class MyAppListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //here the application has been deployed
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        String contextPath = servletContext.getContextPath();
        //do what you want/need with context path
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //here the application is being undeployed
    }
}
```

Then just configure the listener properly in web.xml

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>the.package.of.your.MyAppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: `getContextPath()` gives me only the /myApp bit, I'm looking for the complete url: `http://myserver:8080/myApp`